# What are the coverings of femoral hernia?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, medicine

It was my Viva question and I was really puzzled.I know what is femoral hernia and it route like the abdominal content moves down the femoral canal and further through the saphenous opening and all but I have no idea about it's coverings.Can anyone please help me

Answer (score 2):

Femoral hernia coverings (from inside out):

- Peritoneum
- Femoral septum (extraperitoneal fatty, connective and lymphoid tissue)
- Tranversalis fascia
- Cribriform fascia
- Superficial fascia
- Skin

[image]

*Image source: [SurgWiki](http://www.surgwiki.com/wiki/File:Ch40-fig7.jpg), Creative Commons Licence*

Sources:

- [SurgWiki: Hernias](http://www.surgwiki.com/wiki/File:Ch40-fig7.jpg)
- [SlideShare: Femoral hernia, p. 12](https://www.slideshare.net/chengjinting/femoral-hernia-84080889)
- [EarthsLab: Femoral canal](https://www.earthslab.com/anatomy/femoral-canal/)
- [Textbook of Anatomy Abdomen and Lower Limb;, Volume 2, By Vishram Singh, p.45](https://books.google.si/books?id=zq1jDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA45&lpg=PA45&dq=%22femoral%20hernia%22%20%22superficial%20fascia%22%20%22cribriform%22&source=bl&ots=cJtTmZYEJ5&sig=ACfU3U39ywn0weY3ZNQrRHZaeAzs88cRog&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjK6aGj1ozlAhVBPFAKHUz_D10Q6AEwFHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22femoral%20hernia%22%20%22superficial%20fascia%22%20%22cribriform%22&f=false)